# Extracting highways from a string using regular expression matcher

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am using regular expression matcher to extract portion of string from a text.

For e.g. Here is the text :

```
var str = "I-35 South / US-290 West"
```

I would like to extract two strings,

1. I-35 South
2. US-290 West.

I tried the below pattern, its returning true on test method. However not returning expected matches.

```
var pattern = /^(I|US|TX)-\d{1,3}.*$/

str.match(pattern)
```

Returns

1. "I-35 South / US-290 West"
2. "I"

If I remove ".*" matching is not happening.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `.*` means match anything, and the $ at the end means that it's supposed to end with that character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `matches` we can try:

```js
var str = "I-35 South / US-290 West";
var highways = str.match(/[A-Z]+-\d+ \w+/g);
console.log(highways);
```

Note that if your input would always be a slash-separated list of highways, you might as well just split on that separator:

```js
var str = "I-35 South / US-290 West";
var highways = str.split(/\s*\/\s*/);
console.log(highways);
```

Comment: Awesome!, I will accept /[A-Z]+-\d+ \w+/g

Answer (score 1):

As you want multiple matches in the same string, you can omit the anchors `^` and `$` and also omit `.*` which will match until the end of the string.

To get the the match only, you can also turn the capture group into a non capture group.

Note to add the `/g` flag after the regex to get all matches.

```
\b(?:I|US|TX)-\d{1,3} \w+
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:I|US|TX)` Match any of the alternatives
- `-\d{1,3}` Match `-` and 1-3 digits
- `\w+` Match a space and 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nj5tTo/1)

```js
var str = "I-35 South / US-290 West"
var pattern = /\b(?:I|US|TX)-\d{1,3} \w+/g;
console.log(str.match(pattern));
```